# How much (sunflower) lecithin should be used to emulsify each gram of fat in water?

Tags: oil, emulsion, fat

I read around and haven't found a clear answer. Is there a minimum ratio of lecithin (preferably powder) to fat required to fully emulsify it in water? Does the amount of water matter? And does the type of fat (vegetable oil vs animal fat [such as from milk]) matter?

Thank you.

Comment: I will add that I tried looking through scholarly reports which might have involved these questions, but almost all require subscription to view the complete reports. I found one freely-available report which tested emulsification of whey protein in oil:water mixtures, and at the very least it was reported that the emulsion was more stable when the lecithin was dissolved in the oil first, but it wasn't clear if the tested lecithin ratios were in comparison to the volume/weight of the entire mixture or just of the oil or just of the water, and whether the oil:water ratio should be considered.

Comment: I've read several times that researchers/authors are allowed to distribute their studies free of charge if they choose, and since they aren't paid royalties by the journals that publish their work, they will usually happily send you a copy. So you might consider emailing the author(s) of the study you found that might answer the question.